# casperjs click() a form element to submit, wait, run queries on next page?

Tags: casperjs

I would like to click a submit button, wait for the next page to load, then obtain html on that second page.. I do the start, then and run, but the then step is still run on the first page. Any ideas?

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var site = 'http://www.example.com';
var data = {}; 

casper.start(site, function() {
     this.evaluate(function() {
        $('input[type="submit"]:first').click();
    }); 
});

casper.then(function() {
    data.body = this.evaluate(function() {
        var rows = $('#content table:first tbody tr');
        var listings = rows.eq(3).text();
        var count = rows.eq(4).text();
        return {
            listings: listings,
            count: count
        };  
    }); 
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(data.body.listings);
    this.exit();            
});
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem. My redirect is also not happening, but I submit a form instead of clicking on a button. Maybe answers to my question will shed some light on yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181669/why-does-casperjs-form-submit-not-redirect-to-the-next-page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This only partially solves your problem, but you can confirm that you've made it to the second page using waitFor. For example:

```
this.waitFor(function check() {
    return (this.getCurrentUrl() === PAGE_2_URL);
},
function then() { // step to execute when check() is ok
    this.echo('Navigated to page 2', 'INFO');
},
function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
    this.echo('Failed to navigate to page 2', 'ERROR');
});
```

Comment: There is `waitForUrl()` in CasperJS 1.1.

Answer (score 4):

Its a good idea use waitForResource to wait the page load finished, see documentation here [documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource)

example:

```
casper.waitForResource(function checkAuth(validcredentials) {
                    return validcredentials;
                }, function onReceived() {
                    if (authTitle !== this.getTitle()) {
                        this.log('Autenticação realizada com sucesso, aguarde...');
                    } else { 
                        // this.capture('pic3.png');
                        this.log('Usuario ou senha invalidos!', 'ERROR');
                        this.die('User or password invalids!', 1); }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with doubleclick. Make sure the click event is actually fired. I suspect this is the cause of running the next step within the same content.

Comment: Any idea what I should do to confirm a click was successful? If it actually was successful it would be navigating to the next page. I feel like Casper needs a more reliable solution for changing pages if click() on an anchor doesn't work 100% of the time.